# How can I safely use eval in php?

Tags: php, eval

I know some people may just respond "never" as long as there's user input.  But suppose I have something like this:

```
$version = $_REQUEST['version'];
$test = 'return $version > 3;';
$success = eval($test);
```

This is obviously a simplified case, but is there anything that a user can input as `version` to get this to do something malicious?  If I restrict the type of strings that `$test` can take on to comparing the value of certain variables to other variables, is there any way anybody can see to exploit that?

**Edit**

I've tried running the following script on the server and nothing happens:

```
<?php
  $version = "exec('mkdir test') + 4";
  $teststr = '$version > 3;';
  $result = eval('return ' . $teststr);
  var_dump($result);
?>
```

all I get is `bool(false)`.  No new directory is created.  If I have a line that actually calls `exec('mkdir test')` before that, it actually does create the directory.  It seems to be working correctly, in that it's just comparing a string converted to a number to another number and finding out the result is false.

Comment: As said below, `$success = eval($test)` doesn't work as expected in PHP (different from JavaScript). You will have to do the assignment in the evaled string.

Comment: Two things: you're completely trusting user input. Not only that, you're thus allowing the user to execute arbitrary code. Voila, instant exploit! (yes, I'd say "never use eval")

Comment: I've tried injecting code in there, and it's just not working for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of yours question.  Are you trying to "proof"  something? What is it that you trying to establish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this. Only accept ints.

If you must accept strings, don't.

If you still think you must. Don't!

And lastly, if you still, after that, think you need strings. JUST DON'T!

Comment: For comments saying you can protect strings. Yes you can. If you REALLY know what you are doing. Really REALLY REALLY know what you are doing. And OP doesn't. Nothing against him. Neither do I. And neither do you, most likely.

Comment: See my edited comment above.  I can't find any string that injects code in my example.  Is there anything unsafe about it?

Comment: Just because you can't find something. Doesn't mean an attacker cannot. It seems you missed my point. Also, you aren't using eval on user input, anymore.

Comment: I think you missed my point too.  No matter what the value of $version is, it is treated as a string and compared to to the number 3.  It is not evaluated under any circumstances, isn't that correct?

Comment: That's what the last thing I said was. But by doing this, how exactly is it any different than not using eval at all? You've used eval on a static string. IE: $result = $_REQUEST['version'] > 3; does the same thing without an eval.

Comment: The reason I'm using an eval is because the contents of $teststr come from somewhere else (a database, not user-supplied).

Comment: That's a bad idea too. Databases should be considered user input. You never can be sure how the data got there. And this would then be a window for an SQL injection attack that leads to an eval manipulation attack that leads to your server being pwned in one of a variety of really suck ways. Not all of which you'd even know happened.

Comment: A solution to that problem would be to have references in the DB and a switch statement that calls various functions or itself contains the swapped up code.

Comment: The database is read-only, not SQL-based, and is essentially as secure as the php file itself.  If they can edit the database, they could just as easily edit the php file.  Any problem with using eval now?

Comment: I'm essentially storing validation strings in the database.  It loops through various validation strings, finds the first one that returns true, and does something based on that string.  The design is to keep the validation strings out of the PHP file on purpose, so I can change the database if I need to without needing to modify the all-purpose handler.  But that's not really part of the question.  Do I or do I not need to worry about eval being a point of code injection when used in this way?

Comment: Worry? Probably not, but only if every possible way along that chain is secure. As long as the database stays locked and you never move to a new system that you can access remotely, forgetting about the eval. So on. The problem with eval is if you forget about it, even just once, you can end up in jail some day saying to yourself "WTF, I didn't hack into the pentagon!!!" You need a compelling damn reason to do it. And convenience ain't compelling enough.

Answer (score 3):

Ohhhh boy!

```
$version = "exec('rm-rf/...') + 4"; // Return 4 so the return value is "true" 
                                    // after all, we're gentlemen!
$test = "return $version > 3"; 
eval($test);
```

:)

You would have to do at least a `filter_var()` or `is_numeric()` on the input value in this case.

By the way, the way you use `eval` (assigning its result to `$success`) doesn't work in PHP. You would have to put the assignment into the eval()ed string.

Comment: At least the $success assignment works because I'm returning the value inside the eval statement.

Comment: @Ed I stand corrected, it is indeed possible to `return` something from the eval statement. Your code is fine

Comment: As for the exec thing, I've tried writing a simple test with injecting an exec and it's just not doing anything  I tried a simple exec('mkdir test').  Any idea why?

Comment: I think I see the issue now:  Using double-quotes around $test.  If I don't use double-quotes, or if I load the value of test from a file, then it wouldn't parse $version beforehand.  Is there any way to compromise the system if I don't use double-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

yes, anything. I would use `$version = (int)$_REQUEST['version'];` to validate the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise with your definitions of "malicious" or "safe". Consider for example

```
exec("rm -rf /");

echo "enlarge your rolex!";

while(true) echo "*";
```

all three snippets are "malicious" from the common sense point of view, however technically they are totally different. Protection techniques that may apply to #1, won't work with other two and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make this safe would be to ensure that `$version` is a number BEFORE you try to `eval`.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to remove everything except numbers (0-9): preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $version);